# How to send "B00000100" via bluetooth using MIT App Inventor 2?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been working on this issue for a few hours now and i just can't figure out how to send the data without it getting corrupted or changed into something else. Basically, i need to send a byte, in this format: "B00000001" or "B00000100" (without quotes) to my Arduino which is connected to a Bluetooth module (HC-05) and this will then trigger some event. I tried sending the data as a string and it didn't work, so i tried as an integer and it was trying to convert it into another number?! I have no idea how to proceed.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.